# Вывод значений вектора

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть заполненный вектор, хочу вывести значения в вывод. Компилятор ругается.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v2;
    for (int i=1; i != 30; ++i)
        v2.push_back(i);
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Хочу понять как перемножить пару векторов поэлементно, т.е. первый элемент с каждым элементов второго и т.д. Затем разобраться с проверкой на точный квадрат. Дабы найти все пары чисел, являющиеся точным квадратом.

Comment: "Компилятор ругается." - матом?

Comment: Одних отступов в С++ недостаточно. Это не питон.

Comment: Отступы в C++ нужны программисту для улучшения визуального восприятия кода. Компилятор же вас правильно поймёт, если вы тело цикла поместите внутрь фигурных скобок `{ }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v2;
    for (int i=1; i != 30; ++i)
    {
        v2.push_back(i);
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Скобочки пропустили...